# Problem while editing symfony FOSUser (The option "mutiple" does not exist. Defined options are: )

Tags: symfony-3.4

so I faced this problem while trying to edit the FOSUser bundle on my symfony 3.4 project that I am working on using PHPStorm.I added roles hierarchy that is suitable to my project requirements.
But I found this problem that is stopping me from moving forward and continuing my project.
Any kind of help would be much appreciated.
PS: I added photos of the security.yml and RegistrationFormType.php as well as the problem encountred while executing on the navigator (chrome).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVYU.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V4Dm.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptg8J.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post an answer because i cant add a coment yet. Change 'mutiple' to 'multiple' in 'roles'